# How can I do a Unit Test with Junit and mockito in Java on methods that read a path and file?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit4

How I can test a method that reads a route and file and receives a date as a parameter:

```
public String getFileAE(String fecha) {
    String fileName = null;
    String filePath = null;
    File file = null;
    
    try {
        logger.info("Leyendo archivo ejecutivos facultados");
        fileName = ConstantsFiles.FILE_NAME_AE + fecha + ConstantsFiles.FILE_EXTENSION;
        filePath = ConstantsFiles.FILE_PATH_AE + fileName;
        logger.info(filePath);
        
        file = new File(filePath);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            logger.error("Error, el archivo no existe: " + filePath);
            return "";
        }
        return filePath;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("Error, el archivo no se pudo leer: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
    return filePath;    
}
```

Comment: I'd create another component, a `FileFactoryService`, with a method `newFile(String path)` which would just call `new File(path)`. Then you can mock that component and the value `newFile` returns. Incidentally, your method returns the same value whether or not there is an exception. That seems wrong.

Comment: tgdavies Sorry, I didn't understand "with a new file(string path) method that would just call new file(path)", could you be a bit more specific?

Answer (score 1):

You can't mock `new File(filePath)`, so you need to extract that into another component:

```
class FileFactoryService {
  File newFile(String path) {
    return new File(path);
  }
}
```

Which you use in your class:

```
class MyClass {
  private final FileFactoryService fileFactoryService;

  public MyClass(FileFactoryService fileFactoryService, ...) {
    this.fileFactoryService = fileFactoryService;
    ...
  }

  public String getFileAE(String fecha) {
    ...
    file = fileFactoryService.newFile(filePath);
    ...
  }
}
```

Then in your test:

```
@Test
public void testGetFileAE() {
  FileFactoryService fileFactoryService = mock(FileFactoryService.class);
  File file = mock(File.class);
  when(fileFactoryService.newFile("/the/path/we/expect.ext").thenReturn(file);
  when(file.exists()).thenReturn(true);
  MyClass myClass = new MyClass(fileFactoryService , ... );
  assertEquals("/the/path/we/expect", myClass.getFileAE("expect"));
}
```

Comment: Yeah agree, we need to have a testable implementation to write unit tests, like you extract in to new method to create new file.